# Proper Case Selection in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code that should convert my text to Proper Case but its not working.
I start by marking the cells I want converted and then run this macro:

```
Sub ProperCase()

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

Set rng = Selection

For Each cell In rng

Next cell

cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Proper(cell.Value)

End Sub
```

But Excel gives me runtimer error 91

Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: The `Next cell` line has to be after the `cell.Value = ...`. Otherwise you don't do anything in the loop.

Comment: Ofcourse, thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to make exceptions for some words?

Comment: FYI you don't need a loop for that: `selection.value = application.proper(selection)`

Comment: The straight forward thing for exceptions would be an `If` statement but a little more elegant/readable (in my opinion) would be a `Select Case` where one case does nothing (all the words you want to exclude) and the default case (`Case Else`) does the replacement-

Comment: I tried your code removing the loop but it kills all the data ehen you select to columns that are not next to eachother like A & C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will overwrite formula - tell it to ignore formula.
Rather than use `WorksheetFunction.Proper` use `StrConv(value, conversion_type)`.

```
Sub ProperCase()

    Dim rng As Range

    'Use special cells so as not to overwrite formula.
    For Each rng In Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Cells
        Select Case StrConv(rng.Value, vbLowerCase)
            'Ensure all exception words are lower case.
            Case "bob", "word2", "dave", "some other words"
                rng.Value = StrConv(rng.Value, vbLowerCase)
            Case Else
                'StrConv is the VBA version of Proper.
                rng.Value = StrConv(rng.Value, vbProperCase)
        End Select
    Next rng

End Sub
```

**Edit:**  Added `SELECT...CASE` to exclude words as per comment.

Comment: This is a great elegant solution, is there a way to instead of just doing nothing to the selection to force it to lowercase instead?

Comment: Just replace the `'Do nothing` comment with `rng.Value = StrConv(rng.Value, vbLowerCase)` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263373(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: Its not working it says: Else without an if statement.

Comment: Check your code again - delete just  `'Do nothing` and replace with the code in my comment.  Sounds like you've deleted the `End Select Statement` or `Next rng` statements.

Comment: i copied your code and replaced do nothing with rng.Value = StrConv(rng.Value, vbLowerCase),m still not working, same else without if error

Comment: Have you put `rng.Value = StrConv(rng.Value, vbLowerCase),m`?  Remove the `,m` from the end - that's part of the msdn link in my comment (code line finishes at the close bracket).

Comment: Its not working even when I just take the first version without the lowercase, just the do nothing version.

Comment: Doh!  Just realised _my_ mistake... change `ELSE` to `CASE ELSE`.  Sorry!  I'll update the post.

Comment: Its working now but the exceptions dont, Excel ignores them and puts everything in proper

Comment: A couple of things could be causing that - either you've got `vbProperCase` instead of `vbLowerCase` or, as is more probable, you're matching **word2** with **Word2**.  I hadn't considered that the `Case` statement is case sensitive - update `Select Case rng.Value` to `Select Case StrConv(rng.Value, vbLowerCase)` - this will convert the value being matched to lower case (not the actual value) and make sure all the exceptions are in lower case only.  I'll update my answer to include this.

Answer (score 0):

`cell.value` should come before you iterate to next cell:

```
Sub ProperCase()

    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

    Set rng = Selection

    For Each cell In rng
        cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Proper(cell.Value)
    Next cell


End Sub
```